# Find the point on the parabola

Tags: calculus

Find the point on the parabola $y^{2}=2x$ that is closest to the point $(1,13)$.

What is the parabola? and please show the process

Comment: [The parabola is $2x = y^2 \iff x = \frac 12 y^2$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y^2+%3D+2x) This is a "horizontal" parabola, whose vertex is the origin, and which opens to the right, symmetrical about the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the distance is:
$d^2=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$. In your case: $x_0=1,y_0=13$. So you get:
$$d^2=(x-1)^2+(y-13)^2$$ but you know: $y=\sqrt{2x}$.
So, you have:
$$d^2=(x-1)^2+(\sqrt{2x}-13)^2$$
Now you have to find the minimum of the distance, so you have to calculate: $$\frac{d}{dx}(d^2)=\frac{2x^{3/2}-13\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x}}=0$$ From this equation you get: $x=4.388...$ and $y=2.962...$

Comment: No, you *don't* get that. You get an exact answer that decimal expansion only obscures.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I agree, but I supposed user108727 wanted to know the method, no matter about an exact or numerical solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You'll want to minimize the distance between the points $(1,13)$ and $\left(\frac12y^2,y\right).$ It's enough to minimize the square of the distance.

Comment: Not too little, not too much! Just right! +1